# Как распознать объекты на уже распознанном элементе изображения?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов

Сейчас я занимаюсь задачей распознавания человека на фотографии, а также определения наличия прыщей на его лице. Определить человека получилось при помощи обучения свёрточной нейронной сети в Keras, а как дальше определить, есть ли у него прыщи или нет, я не знаю.

Нужно ли выделять участок с лицом и затем анализировать его текстуру с помощью нейросети, которая была обучена на фотографиях участков кожи с прыщами? Как это можно сделать?

Буду рад прочитать все идеи. Спасибо!